# How would you graph a logarithm whose base is a fraction that is not $\frac{1}{b}$ by hand?

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

How would you do that without a calculator, so that $y$ would be an integer or some other non-excessively long number?

Example, $y=\log_{\frac{3}{10}}x$

I can get the key point $(\frac{3}{10},1)$ and the x-intercept $(1,0)$ but not a third point.

Is this possible?

Comment: For small (by absolute value) integer m you can find points ((3/10)**m, m). E.g. (0.09, 2), (0.027, 3), (10/3, -1), (100/9, -2), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

For any $r > 0, r \neq 1, x > 0$ you have that

$$\log_r(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(r)}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, for a fixed value $r$, the RHS denominator of $\ln(r)$ is easily computed using a hand-held or online calculator.  Further, you should be able to obtain a copy of the graph of $y = \ln(x)$, either manually, by plotting selecting points via a calculator, considering the varying slope (AKA derivative) of the graph, or finding an online copy of the graph.

Then, using (1) above, assuming that an accurate enough graph of $y = \ln(x)$ is to be construed as *known*, it is then simply a matter of applying to the graph, the **fixed** scalar $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{\ln(r)}.$

Note that applying a fixed scalar to an existing $2$ dimensional graph does not alter the *shape of the graph*.  Instead, it is as if the $y$-axis scaling has simply been altered by the scalar.